# Add_action to wp_head via functions.php

Tags: hooks, single

I installed the Twenty Seventeen theme and a child theme. Now I want to add the following code to `functions.php` to add meta data to the `<head>` tag using the `wp_head` action:

```
if ( is_single() ) echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "meta-head", true); ?>
```

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
add_action ('wp_head','hook_inHeader');
function hook_inHeader() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "meta-head", true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Enable the debug mode, and find out what's wrong with `$post`.

Answer (score 11):

The reason the code posted is not working is that `$post` is not referencing the global `$post` variable, which is the goal here.

Using [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) is a good way of accessing the ID associated with the current post. That's how I'd suggest doing it, but there are other ways too:

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'hook_inHeader' );
function hook_inHeader() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        // Get the post id using the get_the_ID(); function:
        echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-head', true );

        /* Or, globalize $post so that we're accessing the global $post variable: */
        //global $post;
        //echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'meta-head', true );

        /* Or, access the global $post variable directly: */
        // echo get_post_meta( $GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'meta-head', true );
    }
}
```